# Input set filter function with additional problematic trailing double quote in batch/cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The purpose of this script is to prepare a readline and other input for later (mostly safer) parsing and delimination.

The primary issue is a trailing `set` quote.  Initially I suspected a plethora of things to do with escapes and specials, but debugging has pinpointed the exact cause.

This is the readline input I'm using for the script below, but feel free to get creative (And for those keen to see where this is headed; Yes, without a trailing quote the later filter works beautifully)

```
 _strFilter /VERBOSE /STRING "C:/Documents & Settings" /TESTstr"C:\Users\User" "Hello/Universe & Goodbye;World\"  /_DEBUG "test\stray" "test|stray2" /TESTstr "^^%^^%^^!|#|^^!@|"
```

.

```
@ECHO OFF

echo;&echo Earlier working version ============================================================

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "_userInput=" %* ""
set "_strArray=%_userInput%"
:: additional set filters here
set "_userInput_filter=%_strArray%"
    echo;&echo;Prepared String ----- "%_userInput_filter%"
endlocal

echo;&echo Prefered implementation ============================================================ 

setLocal
set "_userInput=" %* ""         %=(Breaks without quotes, spaces are needed later, though have no impact)=%
call :_strFilter_prepare _userInput_filter "%%_userInput%%"
    echo;&echo;Prepared String ----- "%_userInput_filter%"
endlocal
exit /B

:_strFilter_prepare varName strVal
  setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
:: set _strArray=""%*""         %=(Throws errors)=%
:: set "_strArray=%*"           %=(Throws errors)=%
:: set "_strArray="%*"          %=(Bad syntax)=%
  set "_strArray="%*""          %=(This is where the extra quote gets pulled through)=%
:: additional set filters here
:: for /F "tokens=1,*" %%A in ("%_strArray:~0,-1%") do (    %=(Syntax breaks)=%
  for /F "tokens=1,*" %%A in ("%_strArray%") do (
    endLocal
    set %%~A=%%~B
  )
  exit /B
```

The output is the same for both, yet the prefered implementation has a trailing double quote, which breaks things down the line:

```
Escaped String ----- "" /VERBOSE /STRING "C:/Documents (AMP) Settings" /TESTstr"C:\Users\User" "Hello/Universe (AMP) Goodbye;World\" /_DEBUG "test\stray" "test(BAR)stray2" /TESTstr "(CARET)(CARET)%(CARET)(CARET)%(CARET)(CARET)(EXCLAIM)(BAR)#(BAR)(CARET)(CARET)(EXCLAIM)@(BAR)" """
```

This is using the "correct" `set` method, any other quoting for the `set` commands breaks things.  My aimed output lacks the very last quote, using the preferred implementation.

Comment: Born with a `--verbose` flag set, it's going to take a bit to reduce my question to the minimum.
After a few edits, some debugging, I've got this down to the exact problem with the bare minimum to recreate it, supliferous questions and content now omitted

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most ideal answer, but given long enough, I often tend to figure *something* out.

Though it may not the best solution, the addition of a strategic double quote does make the result managable and now can be parsed easily without major error (and accomodated for in the inner filters).

```
@echo off

setLocal
set "_userInput=" %* "" 
call :_strFilter_prepare _userInput_filter "%%_userInput%%"
    echo;&echo;Prepared String ----- "%_userInput_filter%"
endlocal
exit /B

:_strFilter_prepare varName strVal
  setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  set "_strArray="%*""
:: additional set filters here
  for /F "tokens=1,*" %%A in ("%_strArray%") do (
    endLocal
    set %%~A="%%B
REM          ^ This is the additional quote
REM Though for the larger script %%~B is req.
  )
  exit /B
```

The resulting quotes left are a double quote.  Echo prepends/appends an additional double-double.

Comment: This solution is a bit cleaner downstream than the original lopsided trims, but I can't help but feel like this is still a bit of a hack way to handle the issue.  Or maybe that's just one of those weird cmd parsing quirks I keep reading about